# Big-Step Semantic Inference Rules for Boolean Negation

Tags: boolean-operations

I am working with the following big-step semantic rules for a simple imperative language:
[image: big-step semantic rules]

I would like to add inference rules for boolean negation to this imperative language.
I have come up with the following two inference rules to do so:

[image: boolean negation inference rules]

Do these inference rules properly implement boolean negation in the language? Are these rules complete? If not, what is missing?